# How to send/select the clientcertificate in a HTTPRIO client application?

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, soap

I am creating a client application from WSDL files I imported.
In Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.2 my application automatically asks which client certificate to use (from the Windows certificate store I guess).  In 10.3 it doesn't.

How can I define in my HTTPRIO object to use a specific client certifate (a .p12 file)?

*Edit: 
I made some progress with this line:

`RIO.HTTPWebNode.InvokeOptions := [soPickFirstClientCertificate];`

In Rad Studio 10.3 this will also make the application use the certificate (without asking to pick a certificate).